# Combine multiple text files into a single time series using R

Tags: r

This should be a simple task in r but I can't seem to get it right. I have multiple text files with single column and no header. I just want to combine them to have a single time series. Order doesn't matter. I tried following:

```
library(zoo)
t1 <- read.table("t1.txt") # 3,5,4,..... 
t2 <- read.table("t2.txt") # 5,6,0,.....
so on...
m <- merge(t1 = as.zoo(t1), t2 = as.zoo(t2))
```

I get:

```
1  3  5
2  5  6
3  4  0
.  .  .
.  .  .
```

But I need it like following in single column:

```
3
5
4
.
.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want to `?rbind` the files instead of `merge`ing them

Comment: What about `c(t1, t2)`?

Comment: @shadow: it gives multiple columns. But I need all of them in single column

Comment: @lbe Based on the files I created, the output is posted.  If you don't want header or index, why not convert it to `matrix` and then save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
files <- list.files(pattern="^t\\d+")
z1 <- as.zoo(rbindlist(lapply(files,fread)))

str(z1)
# ‘zoo’ series from 1 to 12
#  Data: int [1:12, 1] 3 5 1 5 7 9 3 4 9 7 ...
#- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr "Col1"
# Index:  int [1:12] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

#### Update

```
attr(z1, 'dimnames') <- NULL
attr(z1, 'index') <- NULL
str(z1)
#‘zoo’ series from  to 
#Data: int [1:12, 1] 3 5 1 5 7 9 3 4 9 7 ...
# Index:  NULL

 z1
   
#[1,] 3
#[2,] 5
#[3,] 1
#[4,] 5
#[5,] 7
#[6,] 9
#[7,] 3
#[8,] 4
#[9,] 9
#[10,] 7
#[11,] 7
#[12,] 9
```

Comment: It also adds single header and index to each value. Is it possible to get only values in text file rather header and index number?

Comment: It worked. I used `m[,1]` and assume index will not be read in column even if I specify `m[,0]` which will give me data frame, column, and rows information